# Creating a random number generator game in JavaScript and cannot get the While loop to keep looping

Tags: javascript

I am trying to create a number generator game where the user has 5 guesses to guess the correct number (between 1 and 10). My code is:

```
/* Random number generator that compares itself with the user input */

var randomGenerator = Math.floor(Math.random() * 10) + 1;
var turns = 5;

while (turns > 0); {
  var user = prompt("Pick a number between one through ten");
  var userInput = parseInt(user);

  if(userInput === randomGenerator) {
    alert("You got it!");
    turns = 0;
  } else if (userInput > randomGenerator) {
    alert("Guess lower!");
    --turns;
  } else if (userInput < randomGenerator) {
    alert("Guess higher!");
    --turns;
  }
}

alert("The number was " + randomGenerator);
```

The code runs once and stops. I want it to run over and over until they run out of guesses or they guess the correct number.

Comment: remove `;` just after the `while`...

Comment: thanks. i did do that but the code still runs the same.

Comment: Sure it works fine without...

Comment: Are you writing this for the browser/node? You cannot block the main thread and wait for user response I don't believe. You will need to usa an asynchronous function that can be called when the user guesses and then reduces his number of guesses if incorrect.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

you have the semicolon after while
remove that and it will work just fine

Comment: Hmm. I wonder why it isn't working that way. I'm writing the code in JS Bin, and was going to transfer it to my text editor once I got it running correct.

Comment: i think js bin has some protection and to prevent an infinite loop, it will stop the iteration

Comment: Added the code to the text editor and it ran perfectly in the browser. Thanks for help!

Comment: see :)  okay you can check this as answered so people now is solved

Answer (score 1):

I would do something like this for the browser....

```
// browser with jquery
(function() {
     var guesses = 5;
     var myRandomNumber = random; // Get random number however you choose

     $('#guessInput').on('submit', function (e) {
           var guess = $(this).val(); 
           if( guess == myRandomNumber ) {
                 // show user congratulations
           } else {
                 guesses -= 1;
           }
           if (guesses === 0) {
                 // say sorry you are out of guesses
                 $(this).prop("disabled", true);
           }
     });
}());
```

You will have to link this to a button that actually submits and then test the input rather than what I have given you.